# Unable to parse POST req with body-parser installed

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a small server app to allow clients to create users. I can't parse the req.body. I tried to read everywhere on Internet but not solution available for me.

I have 2 files on the root of my projet.
- server.js for api config, and
- app.js for app config

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = require('./routes/index.routes');

const app = express();

// Parse incoming requests data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(router);
```

My routes are in routes/index.routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const QuickCreditCtrl = require('../controller/controller');

const router = express.Router();

const baseUrl = '/api/v1';

router.post(`${baseUrl}/auth/signup`, QuickCreditCtrl.createUser);
//router.post(`${baseUrl}/auth/signin`, QuickCreditCtrl.loginUser);

module.exports = router;
```

And controllers on controller/controller.js

```
const user = require('../data/users');

class QuickCreditsCtrl {
    createUser(req, res) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        if (!req.body.name) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                status: '404',
                message: 'name is required',
            });
        } else if(!req.body.email) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                status: 404,
                message: 'email is required'
            });
        }
        const userNew = {
        id: user.length + 1,
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        password: 'user123',
        };
        user.push(userNew);
        return res.status(200).send({
            status: 200,
            //message: 'New user added successfully',
            userNew,
            //data: userNew
        });
    }

}

const QuickCreditCtrl = new QuickCreditsCtrl();

//export default QuickCreditCtrl;
module.exports = QuickCreditCtrl;
```

When I use Postman or curl everything is OK except that I can't access the req.body. I can't figure out why whereas I am using body-parser.

Is there something wrong on my code?

### Edit

I am trying to simplify things but I can't still access the req.body. I've read too much but can't find solution to my problem. In the file below I try to do everything in the app.js file but in vain:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./data/users')

const app = express();

// Parse incoming requests data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/v1/auth/signup', (req, res) => {
  const data = {
        id: db.length + 1,
        email: req.body.email,
        firstN: req.body.firstN,
        lastN: req.body.lastN,
        password: 'Patie123',
      };
      db.push(data);
      return res.status(200).send({
        status: 200,
        message: 'User created successfully',
        data,
      });
      console.log(data);
});

module.exports = app;
```

What is really wrong with my code? Or how do you access req.body?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access the req.body" ? What happen? Is it empty? An error is thrown?

Comment: Are you take a request with data?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant: I get empty. My userNew var returns only id and password.

Comment: @bam what's the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));` in your code

Comment: I am using Postman. I can't have console.log() output. And, I have edited the question above.

Answer (score 1):

All seems correct.
The most probably cause is that the request hasn't a JSON body.

This middleware

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Works if it finds the header "Content-Type": "application/json".

Comment: You can see my request in the class QuickCreditsCtrl above. I want to create a user.

Comment: I mean the request you made with Postman. Did you correctly set the header "Content-Type": "application/json"? I've tried you're code and using postman. If I remove that header the body of you're request isn't parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting urlencoded to "false":

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Let us know if this fixes that!

EDIT:

I've tried to give a deeper look then, I've noticed this line of code:

```
> router.post(`${baseUrl}/auth/signup`, QuickCreditCtrl.createUser);
> //router.post(`${baseUrl}/auth/signin`, QuickCreditCtrl.loginUser);
```

You have no callback here, you should pass `req` and `res` as parameters:

```
 > router.post(`${baseUrl}/auth/signup`, QuickCreditCtrl.createUser, (req, res) => {
    //HERE YOU HAVE ACCESS TO req.body
}))
```

Source: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: It is just the same. It was false at the beginning, then I tried to put it to true to see if it could resolve something. I can't go forward with my projet 4 days ago because of this small problem that I don't even understand.

Comment: I've edited this answer to include another solution but it needs to be peer reviewed. I think that the problem is with your POST route where you have no callback active with req and res. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: This `QuickCreditCtrl.createUser` is the middleware

Comment: I don't write my functions in the route file. They are in controller file, i.e I can't still access to them!

Comment: Oh I see.. I actually have the same problem of accessing req.body in a middleware, I think it might be a common bug.